# Nashorn--Only one class is used to get its bytecode

Tags: java, nashorn

Nashorn,"Java.extend function returns a type object for a subclass of the specified Java class (or implementation of the specified interface) that acts as a script-to-Java adapter for it."
I passed Java.extend(xxx,{xxx: function(){}}).class get a class object,and I want to write its bytecode on a file.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Nashorn doesn't support this directly, however you can do something yourself using the [Java instrumentation API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.instrument/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html), and implementing a `ClassFileTransformer`.